# obtener los ultimos elementos de tuplas en una lista

Tags: python-3.x

tengo una lista de tuplas con strings adentro parecida a esta: `[("esto", "es"),("una", "lista"),("de", "tuplas")]` y quiero tomar todos los primeros elementos de las tuplas, quedando `["esto", "una", "de"]`.

quise hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```py
array = [("esto", "es"),("una", "lista"),("de", "tuplas")]
a = array[:][0]
print(a)
```

pero me retorna esto: `('esto', 'es')`

Tambien intente cambiar `array[:][0]` por `array[::, 0]` pero me da el error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/joaqu/OneDrive/Escritorio/Informatica/ZZZ_CosasImportantes/Python/prueba0.py", line 2, in <module>
    a = array[::, 1::]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Usa  `a = [e1 for e1, e2 in array]`

Comment: muchas gracias. pero exactamente como funciona?

Comment: se esta iterando sobre los elementos de la lista: `[... for e in array]` pero la sintaxis de python permite hacer la separacion por lo que puedes cambia la tupla `e` por los elementos `e1` y `e2` consiguiendo: `[... for e1, e2 in array]`, pero en tu caso solo quieres el primer elementos entonces solo usamos e1 para construir la nueva lista: `[e1 for e1, e2 in array]`, te recomiendo leer sobre list comprehension

Comment: ok, gracias por la explicacion

Comment: Aunque irrelevante, el título no corresponde con lo que pides luego.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el indice  del elemento  a extraer:

```
 # retorna un arreglo con los primeros elementos 
 #  (índice 0) de las tuplas dentro de un arreglo 

 a =[e[0] for e in array]
```